# Eclipse : Open perl file in default editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to open a perl script file in text editor ?

As if now i'm using the below code to open files in text editor

```
IWorkbenchPage page = Activator.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(new Path(path));
        try {
            IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
        } catch (PartInitException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Text files are opened properly but perl script files are executed. I think it uses the default file association to open the file. How can I change it so that my perl script be opened in text editor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. It bypasses the lookup for default editor in *getEditorId()* (called by *openEditorOnFileStore()*) and directly opens an editor by your choice.

```
String editorId = "some.editor.ID";
IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(new Path(path));
page.openEditor(new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore), editorId);
```

(wild guess code, but hopefully should work)

Comment: I don't have a separate editor. I want to open the perl scripts in default text editor available in Eclipse.

Comment: "Default text editor" depends on a content type, usually determined by file suffix.

Comment: Could you tell me what editor is associated to your file by running this? `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(your.perl.file).getId();`

Comment: thanks dreo for the input. i used the above code with default editor id and it works fine now.